# How to set continuation for CompletableFuture from it's callback conditionally?

Tags: java, completable-future

Given the code below - how the `readAllValuesFuture()` method should be implemented?

Make a call and depending on the result of its `Future`:

- either make the next call and pass the result of the previous one
- or return an aggregated result of all previous calls.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class TestFuture
{
    @Test
    public void testReadAllValues() throws Exception
    {
        counter = 0;
        var list = readAllValues();
        assert list.size() == 10;
        assert counter == 11;
    }

    @Test
    public void testReadAllValuesFuture() throws Exception
    {
        counter = 0;
        var list = readAllValuesFuture().get();
        assert list.size() == 10;
        assert counter == 11;
    }


    // Synchronous logic - plain and simple
    private List<Integer> readAllValues()
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer res = makeFirstRequest();
        while (res != null)
        {
            list.add(res);
            res = makeNextRequest(res);
        }

        return list;
    }

    // Futures - how to implement it?
    private CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> readAllValuesFuture()
    {
        return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(new UnsupportedOperationException());
    }


    private int counter = 0;

    // Assuming this is external code which cannot be changed
    private Integer makeFirstRequest()
    {
        counter++;
        return 0;
    }

    // Assuming this is external code which cannot be changed
    private Integer makeNextRequest(Integer prevValue)
    {
        counter++;
        if (++prevValue < 10)
        {
            return prevValue;
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Assuming this is external code which cannot be changed
    private CompletableFuture<Integer> makeFirstRequestFuture()
    {
        counter++;
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0);
    }

    // Assuming this is external code which cannot be changed
    private CompletableFuture<Integer> makeNextRequestFuture(Integer prevValue)
    {
        counter++;
        if (++prevValue < 10)
        {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(prevValue);
        }

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }
}
```

Real-life use-case:
Implement `listAllTables()` from the example below using `DynamoDbAsyncClient` (`DynamoDbAsyncClient.listTables()` returns `CompletableFuture<ListTablesResponse>` instead of `ListTablesResponse` as `DynamoDbClient.listTables()` does):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is via [`Stream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)):

```
var values = Stream.iterate(
    makeFirstRequestFuture().get(),
    Objects::nonNull,
    previous -> {
        try {
            return makeNextRequestFuture(previous).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
).toList();
```